# Creating File object through filepath?

Tags: angularjs

I have one requirement where i need to create a file object, same like when we upload any file in HTML form. is there any possibility that i can do it with filepath?

```
filepath= "C:\Users\Abhishek.Kumar31\Downloads\abc.pdf"
```

i want to send this created file to back end to perform some action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local file access with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)